# A question in Homotopy of morphisms of Category of complexes of R-modules

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$\newcommand{\hom}{\mathsf{Hom}}\newcommand{\ch}{\mathsf{Ch}}$This question was left as an exercise in my class of topology and I am not able to make enough progress in it.

So, I am posting my proof looking for an attempt here.

Definition: $f,g : C\to D$ two morphisms of complexes. We say that f is homotopic to g if there is a family : $(h_i : C_i \to D_{i+1})_{(i \in \mathbb{Z})}$  of R-linear maps such that : $f_i - g_i = d \circ h_i + h_{i-1} \circ d $ for every $i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The family $(h_i)_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is called homotopy between $f$ and $g$.

Then show that (1)$\simeq$ is an equivalence relation on the set of $\hom_{\ch(R)}(C,D)$.

(2) If $f_1 \simeq f_2$ and $g_1 \simeq g_2$ then $f_1 \circ g_1 \simeq f_2 \circ g_2$.

Attempt: I have prove reflexivity by using the zero morphism $(O_i)_{i\in\Bbb Z}$.

For symmetry: Let $f\simeq g$ which implies: $f_i -g_i=d \circ h_i + h_{i-1} \circ d$ for every $i\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I have to show $g \simeq f$. If I multiply the above equation by $-1$, I get $g_i -f_i= -d \circ h_{i}- h_{i-1} \circ d$.  But how to deal with the $-d$ in 2nd equation so that it comes with $h_i$. Can you please help?

For reflexivity : I have done it because I was given $f_i -g_i=...$ and $g_i -k_i=...$ and I just added them so as to get $f_i -k_i=...$ ,so If $f_i \simeq g_i$ and $g_i \simeq k_i$ , I showed that $f_i \simeq k_i$.

For (2) : I am not able to show this using what is given.

Can you please help me with my questions?

Comment: The MathJax wasn't correct because you wrote `_(i\in\Bbb Z)` but one should encapsulate this with braces: `_{(i\in\Bbb Z)}`

Comment: @FShrike Ok I am sorry, I made this change later. Even before it , It was not working.

Comment: I've made some edits, do you like how it looks?

Comment: @FShrike It looks great. Thank you very much!

Comment: The usual trick to turn (2) into a simpler problem is to notice that it can be reduced to two of its special cases: the one in which f1=g1, and the one in which f2=G2.

Answer (score 1):

For 2), you're nearly there. Indeed, $g_i-f_i=-d\circ h_i-h_{i-1}\circ d$. Since all maps are homomorphisms, if I define $h'_i:=-h_i$ then I have: $$g_i-f_i=d\circ h'_i+h'_{i-1}\circ d,\,\forall i$$And also $(h'_i)_i$ assembles to a morphism of complexes ($h'_id=dh'_i)$. So we get $g\simeq f$.